# Is $\sqrt{I}/I$ finite dimensional?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Is $\sqrt{I}/I$ finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$, where $I$ is a (non-zero) ideal in $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$?

I know the ring is Noetherian, so they are finitely generated.

The question is from an attempt to prove $R/I$ is finite dimensional if and only if $I$ is contained in finitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: What if $I=(x_1^2)$?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, so how do you prove the right to left direction? I can only prove it when $I$ is radical (and using Nullstellensatz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that if $I$ is contained in only finitely many maximal ideals,
then $R/I$ has finite dimension over $\Bbb C$ note that $V(I)$ is a finite set, so that $I(V(I))=\sqrt I$ is the intersection of finitely many
maximal ideals $M_1,\ldots,M_k$ (this all comes from the Nullstellensatz).
Then as $\sqrt I$ is finitely generated,
$I\supseteq \sqrt I^m=\bigcap_j M_j^m$ for some $m$. Then $R/I$ is a quotient of $R/\sqrt I^m\cong \prod_j R/M_j^m$. But all of the $R/M_j^m$
are finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Since you managed to prove it for radical ideals, I will give you a proof of the following:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $R=k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ and $I \subset R$ an ideal. If $R/\sqrt I$ is finite-dimensional as $k$-vector space, so is $R/I$.

Before proving this, let me state

> **Lemma 2.** Let $R=k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ and $I,J \subset R$ two ideals. If $R/I$ and $R/J$ are finite-dimensional as $k$-vector space, so is $R/IJ$.
>
> By choosing $I=J$ and iterating, we of course get that $R/I^n$ is also finite-dimensional for all $n \geq 1$.

**Proof of Lemma 2.**

We have an exact sequence
$$0 \to I/IJ \to R/IJ \to R/I \to 0,$$
hence it suffices to show that $I/IJ$ is finite-dimensional. $I$ is finitely generated, thus we get a surjection $$R^{\oplus n} \twoheadrightarrow I.$$ Tensoring with $R/J$ yields a surjection $$(R/J)^{\oplus n} \twoheadrightarrow I/IJ.$$ The LHS is clearly a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, hence $I/IJ$ is also.

---

**Proof of Lemma 1.**

Since $R$ is notherian, we have $(\sqrt I)^n \subset I$ for some $n$ and thus have a surjection $$R/(\sqrt I)^n \twoheadrightarrow R/I.$$ By Lemma 1 we have that $R/(\sqrt I)^n$ is finite-dimensional and hence the same holds for $R/I$.

---

Note that the proof holds for any noetherian $k$-algebra $R$.